# SQL: querying multi-level hierarchical tables

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child, multi-level

I'm currently trying to create a multi-level structure from different tables 
There are many steps for a test.  The underlying relationship is:

```
1. parent sequence AA
 1.1 child sequence BB
  1.1.1 Step CC
```

There are three tables:

`result_uut` has the following columns:

```
uut_id, uut_serial_number, uut_name
```

`result_seq` has

```
uut_id, step_id, step_parent_id, step_name
```

`result_uut` and `result_seq` is linked by `uut_id`
the parent-child relationship is reflected by `step_id = step_parent_id`

`result_step` has

```
uut_id, step_id, step_parent_id, step_name
```

It is linked to `result_seq` by `result_seq.step_id = result_step.step_parent_id`

I wonder how to let the output have parent seq name, child seq name, and step name, and display in order `(1->1.1->1.1.1->1.1.2...)`.

Comment: What RDBMS system are you using? Each has their own methods to handle hierarchies (SQL Server has CTE's for example, Oracle as "CONNECT BY")

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, I hope I got this right, but if not at least you get the idea (the assumption is that you are working with 32 bit ints for uut_id):

```
select cmb.tag from (select uut_id as tag,concat(lpad(uut_id,10,'0'),repeat('0',20)) as ord or from result_uut 
union
select concat_ws('.',aa.uut_id,bb.uut_id,cc.uut_id) as tag,concat(lpad(aa.uut_id,10,'0'),lpad(bb.uut_id,10,'0'),repeat('0',10)) as ord from result_uut aa join result_seq bb on aa.uut_id = bb.step_parent_uut_id
union
select concat_ws('.',aa.uut_id,bb.uut_id,cc.uut_id) as tag,concat(lpad(aa.uut_id,10,'0'),lpad(bb.uut_id,10,'0'),lpad(cc.uut_id,10,'0') as ord from result_uut aa join result_seq bb on aa.uut_id = bb.step_parent_uut_id join result_step cc on bb.uut_id = cc.step_parent_uut_id) cmb order by ord;
```

The idea is that we use joins to generate the tags, with each tag we generate the ord token that is a 30 digit integer obtained by concatenation of the uut_ids each padded to 10 digits. This hack is necessary because if we just tried to build the actual integer we would overflow 64 bits. Then we union, order by ord and throw away the ord with the help of a simple sub-query.